# python3 dictionary, values as a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, python-3.4

The following code does not have any problem in Python 2.7, however in Python 3.4.3, throws `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

```
import numpy as np
def c1():
        mat=[]
        mat.append(np.array(map(float,np.random.rand(7))))
        return mat
mylist=[]
mydict_={}
mydict_['dog']=c1()
mydict_['big']=c1()

justKeys={label:1 for label in list(mydict_.keys())}

for idx, word in enumerate(justKeys.keys()):
        mylist.append(np.array(map(float, mydict_[word][0])))
```

What should I do in order to the list `mylist` in both python2.7 and 3.4 get the same results?

Comment: my guess will be the .keys() as of http://blog.labix.org/2008/06/27/watch-out-for-listdictkeys-in-python-3

Comment: Thanks. Adding copy().keys() doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with the dictionary methods, but the `map` function, which is changed in Python 3 to return an iterator rather than a list. Numpy doesn't handle the iterators properly, so you need to add a `list` call to fix things:

```
def c1():
    mat=[]
    mat.append(np.array(list(map(float,np.random.rand(4,7)))))
    return mat
```

The rest of your code is a bit confusing, as you're creating a new dictionary, without any useful contents, then enumerating the keys of the new dictionary without using the indexes. It seems like you could just use `my_list = [x[0] for x in dict_.values()]` and have the same result (since the first item in the value lists is already a numpy array of floats, once you fix `c1` as above).

Comment: Thanks gain. @Blckknght quick question: are  mat.append(np.array(list(map(float,np.random.rand(7))))) and  mat.append(np.random.rand(7)) same thing? I mean can be used interchangeably?